# Managing configuration for open source projects

Tags: configuration, open-source, configuration-management

For the past few projects I use a BitBucket private repository to keep production ready configurations for different projects.
Each project in that repository has its own branch where it lives to keep sensitive and private information off public eyes.

Some projects are open source and at the same time live in a real production environment; when time comes to deployment using tools like `chef`, `fabric` etc. I just checkout necessary branch regarding to the project and upload configuration to production servers.

I'm curious about how do you manage configuration for open source projects when you have to manage configs for production and keep project open sourced at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: application repositories should not contain any deployment-specific configuration.

While it's true that configuration files that are not application code often find their way into project repositories for ease of use, it's generally a) bad security practice (hence your reluctance to open source it) and b) a violation of separation of concerns.

Instead you should create a separate repository for all of your application deployment and scripting.  Files in the deployment repository will reference your application repositories.  Following this pattern, the application repositories contains the "what" and the deployment repository contains the "how" -- which will often vary from deployment to deployment.

Exceptions to this rule include scripts or configuration that never change across all your deployments (e.g. a `Procfile` or a daemon script), and should therefore remain in your application repository.